# how to compare all the row values of two tables which are identical in structure

Tags: plsql

I want to compare the all rows in two tables like below.

TABLEA(ID,NAME,EMAIL,MOBILE,ADDRESS),
TABLEB(ID,NAME,EMAIL,MOBILE,ADDRESS).

Here I have the above tables with 20 columns each in real.

When ever a new row inserted into the tables, I need to compare newly inserted row in two tables, if any column mismatch, put into another table.

For example:
TABLEA(1234,ABCDEF,78699EE7,INDIA)
TABLEB(1234,ABCDEF,78699876,INDIA)
Above Mobile number is not matched, I need to insert column name Mobile into another table.

Please help me on this.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are few ways to do it. But one way comes to my mind using SQL only using [UNION ALL](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/union_all.php):

```
INSERT INTO your_other_table(id, name, email, mobile, address) 
     SELECT id, name, email, mobile, address
       FROM tableA
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, name, email, mobile, address
       FROM tableB;
```

However, it is not clear, *when* you need to run this. Since the INSERT occurs to both tables, does it happen within the same transaction. If so, then the script above can be wrapped in a trigger. If the INSERT occurs in different transactions and always, in the same order (e.g., tableA then tableB), then you can again wrap it in the trigger on tableB. Otherwise, you'll have to run it separately.

Notice, the script above, will compare the entire tables, and not only the newly inserted rows. So If any update happened on any row in either one of the tables, and not the other, that row will be inserted in the third table as well.